# Android, Java, Choose image from gallery. Store link and open later

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I want to select one or more images in application (`Activity`) and use them in `Service`. I receive `Uri`s using `Intent` like this:

```
Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
        android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
galleryIntent.setType("image/*");
galleryIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true);
galleryIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(galleryIntent, "Select Picture"), RESULT_LOAD_IMG);
```

`Uri`s I get work but only for some time. From what I understand `Uri`s are temporary. In my case I need permanent links to image files.

Is there a simple way to receive usable (in this situation) link to an image file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a simple way to receive usable (in this situation) link to an image file?

Copy the image to your app's internal storage.

On Android 4.4+, you could use `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT` and the Storage Access Framework, instead of `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` (or, worse, `ACTION_PICK`). With the Storage Access Framework, you can request to take persistent permissions for the `Uri`, which increases the odds that you will be able to access the content in the future. However, even in that case, the user can always get rid of the image in question, eliminating your access to it.